# Maximum dimension of sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

While implementing a third order Markov chain, I got an error, insinuating that there is a maximum dimension of sparse matrices.

E.g. asking for the following sparse matrix

```
T = spalloc(1e12,1e12,1e5);
```

I get the error

> Error using sparse
>   Requested 1000000000000x1000000000000 (7450.6GB) array exceeds
>   maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than
>   this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become
>   unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more
>   information.

From how I understand sparse matrices, the matrix should take up ~3*8*1e5 = 2.4 MB of memory (2 doubles for the coordinates and a double for each non-zero entry). Which is significantly less than the proclaimed 7450.6GB in the error.

Is my understanding of sparse matrices wrong? or what is going wrong? And probably most importantly, are there any way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: The problem is when you want to use linear indexes to access elements of the matrix. If MATLAB uses 64 bit integers for indexing your matrix requires a 80 bit number to index into the last element. Also functions such as find can not return such a number. As a workaround you can split the matrix into 4 submatrices.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Though the splitting seems a bit tedious, as *4* submatrices wont do.

Comment: Your understanding of sparse matrices is wrong. This matrix requires a vector with 1e12 elements, and two vectors with 1e5 elements. MATLAB uses the [compressed sparse column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_(CSC_or_CCS)) format. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/126295-memory-usage-in-sparse-matrix#comment_209306) for a calculation of the actual memory usage.